# Count Missing Each row for a mix of numeric and Character variables

Tags: count, sas

I need to count the number of missing for **each row/observation** for **a mix of numeric and character** variables. Over 300 variables, not possible to do by proc freq and count. Thank you for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpRCw.jpg)
[g ][2]

Comment: PROC FREQ is the exact correct solution, what makes you think it isnt?

Comment: Based on your example image of one row of data with no missing values.  Is the answer zero.  If I understand what you want CMISS is the function you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, which uses PROC FREQ and formats for missing numeric and character variables. When you apply the formats, you get only two categories per variable: Missing and Not Missing.

This is a fully worked example. You will need to modify it very slightly to get your desired results.

Depending on exactly what you want, you can either use the LONG data set output or output data set specified, in this case WANT.

*create sample data to work with;

```
data class;
    set sashelp.class;

    if age=14 then
        call missing(height, weight, sex);

    if name='Alfred' then
        call missing(sex, age, height);
    label age="Fancy Age Label";
run;

*set input data set name;
%let INPUT_DSN = class;
%let OUTPUT_DSN = want;
*create format for missing;

proc format;
    value $ missfmt ' '="Missing" other="Not Missing";
    value nmissfmt .="Missing" other="Not Missing";
run;

*Proc freq to count missing/non missing;
ods select none;
*turns off the output so the results do not get too messy;
ods table onewayfreqs=temp;

proc freq data=&INPUT_DSN.;
    table _all_ / missing;
    format _numeric_ nmissfmt. _character_ $missfmt.;
run;

ods select all;
*Format output;

data long;
    length variable $32. variable_value $50.;
    set temp;
    Variable=scan(table, 2);
    Variable_Value=strip(trim(vvaluex(variable)));
    presentation=catt(frequency, " (", trim(put(percent/100, percent7.1)), ")");
    keep variable variable_value frequency percent cum: presentation;
    label variable='Variable' variable_value='Variable Value';
run;

proc sort data=long;
    by variable;
run;

*make it a wide data set for presentation, with values as N (Percent);

proc transpose data=long out=wide_presentation (drop=_name_);
    by variable;
    id variable_value;
    var presentation;
run;

*transpose only N;

proc transpose data=long out=wide_N prefix=N_;
    by variable;
    id variable_value;
    var frequency;
run;

*transpose only percents;

proc transpose data=long out=wide_PCT prefix=PCT_;
    by variable;
    id variable_value;
    var percent;
run;

*final output file;

data &Output_DSN.;
    merge wide_N wide_PCT wide_presentation;
    by variable;
    drop _name_;
    label N_Missing='# Missing' N_Not_Missing='# Not Missing' 
        PCT_Missing='% Missing' N_Not_Missing='% Not Missing' Missing='Missing' 
        Not_missing='Not Missing';
run;

title "Missing Report of &INPUT_DSN.";

proc print data=&output_dsn. noobs label;
run;
```

https://gist.github.com/statgeek/2de1faf1644dc8160fe721056202f111

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to loop over all variables and count how many are missing:

```
* Create sample data to work with;
data class;
    set sashelp.class;

    if age=14 then
        call missing(height, weight, sex);

    if name='Alfred' then
        call missing(sex, age, height);
run;

* Count number of missing variables for each row;
data want (drop=i);
   set class;
   array nvar {*} _numeric_;
   array cvar {*} _character_;

   no_missing = 0;

   * Loop over all numeric variables;
   do i=1 to dim(nvar);
      no_missing + missing(nvar{i});
   end;

   * Loop over all character variables;
   do i=1 to dim(cvar);
      no_missing + missing(cvar{i});
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Likely a lot easier for most people to understand for sure :) I'd modify your solution very slightly so that it only output for the last record using the data set END option.

Comment: As I understand the question, the count is needed for every row and therefore every line needs to be outputted(?)

Comment: I suppose that's for OP to clarify.